# Checkbox looks like Radiobutton WPF

Tags: wpf

This is probably a dumb question but I have a Checkbox user control that I place in some xaml and when I run the code, the checkbox looks like a radio button instead of a checkbox.

xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,7,0,0" >
        <local:ControlCheckbox x:Name="cbAutoZoom" CheckBoxName="AutoZoom"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

ControlCheckbox:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0">
    <Viewbox x:Name="vbCheckbox" Margin="0" Height="60">
        <CheckBox x:Name="cbCB" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="Black" Checked="cbCB_Checked" Unchecked="cbCB_Unchecked">
            <CheckBox.BorderBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF7B7979" Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </CheckBox.BorderBrush>
        </CheckBox>
    </Viewbox>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbCheckBoxName" Text="xxxxxx" FontSize="13.333" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="4,0,0,0" MaxWidth="230" Height="18" >
        <TextBlock.Foreground>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF646464" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.967"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </TextBlock.Foreground>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Unfortunately my reputation is not high enough to post a picture of my problem...

Comment: can you post a screenshot of it next to a normal checkbox and a normal radio button?

Comment: Did someone override the default style for the CheckBox so that it looks like a RadioButton?   Look for a style in a ResourceDictionary that has an entry for CheckBox and sets the Template property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt see any issue here. I am able to see same checkbox as you are expecting.

[image: UnChecked]

[image: Checked]

[image: Multiple Checkboxes]

Comment: More than one control boxes are also working as expected. adding image in answer as cant show in this commment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone...figured out my problem...I was using a Theme and apparently that is how the checkbox was rendering as a Radiobutton.  I commented out the Theme and the checkbox rendered as Hemant's code above.

See I knew it was a dumb question...sorry to have bothered y'all!